# NSObject subclass as a property

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to use my class as a property in my project. The idea is that i have a class which contains all list ellements. The basic idea i show below in graph:[image]
So i have a myContainerClass object, and i want to do in some other class:
@property (strong,nonatomic) MyContainerClass *obj;
and here i have error! I figure out that i can only use Foundations type as a @property. But Why? What is replacement for doing that (passing an object)?

Comment: Show code for MyContainerClass and the exact error message.

Comment: Please post here the code for your MyContainer Class .m and .h files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can use any class you like as a property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyContainerClass* obj;
```

is perfectly legal provided that the compiler knows that `MyContainerClass` is a class.  To do that in the header file, the best way is to use an `@class` forward declaration:

```
@class MyContainerClass;

@interface SomeOtherClass : NSObject

// method an property declarations

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyContainerClass* obj;

@end
```

And then include the header file in the implementation:

```
#import "MyContainerClass.h"

@implementation SomeOtherClass

@synthesize obj;

// other stuff

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the error you are getting? May be you are not importing MyContainerClass to where you want to use it.

```
#import "MyContainerClass.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a category for an object that you want to add your property to:

```
@interface NSObject (MyContainerClassAdditions)

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyContainerClass *myContainerClass

@end
```

Then implement the setter and getter methods using objective c associated object trick:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation NSObject (MyContainerClassAdditions)

- (void)setMyContainerClass:(MyContainerClass *)myContainerClass {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "myContainerClass", myContainerClass, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);
}

- (MyContainerClass *)myContainerClass {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "myContainerClass");
}

@end
```